# How can I import Facebook events into my Google calendar?

Tags: facebook, google-calendar, synchronization, import

I get a lot of invitations via Facebook, but I keep track of my schedule with Google calendar. Is there any way to automatically import or sync my Facebook events to my Google calendar?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get an iCal link for your Upcoming Events (or Birthdays) that you can import into Google Calendar which will automatically stay up to date.

In Facebook:

1. Go to your [Events](https://www.facebook.com/events/upcoming/).
2. On the left sidebar, click **Calendar**

[image: Events sidebar - Calendar]

3. Go to the lower right portion of the page, where you'll see a message with two links:

   [image: Facebook "you can export your calendar" message]
4. Save the URL for the **Upcoming Events** link. (*This will vary by browser/OS, but is generally something like right-click and **Copy link address***)

The URL should be similar to:

```
webcal://www.facebook.com/ical/u.php?uid=999999999&key=AbCDEf12345AAcd-f
```

(Your actual uid and key values will be different, of course.)

In Google Calendar:

1. Scroll down and open the **Other calendars** menu (on the left)

   [image: "Other calendar" menu]
2. Choose **Add by URL**

   [image: "Add by URL" menu]
3. Paste the webcal URL in the **URL** space then **Add Calendar**

You should now have a calendar **{Your Name}'s Facebook Events** listed under **Other Calendars** and can change the color, details, etc. as needed.

*See also: [Facebook Help - How do I export my events or friends' birthdays?](https://www.facebook.com/help/www/152652248136178)*

Comment: You can get the link from the Export Events link at the bottom of the events page

Comment: Export Events seems to no longer be around in the new Facebook layout (as of Oct 2014).

Comment: @studgeek: I've updated my answer with the new process.

Answer (score 3):

You can use <s>fbCal</s> [fdCal](http://www.fbcal.com/) ( no idea when this name was changed)

> With fdCal get your events and
>   friend's birthdays in Apple iCal,
>   Mozilla Sunbird, Google Calendar,
>   Microsoft Outlook or in your RSS
>   reader! The process can be done in
>   less than a minute, and it's free!

Comment: fdCal has been buggy for ages with Google Calendar. I am unsure as to whether it has been fixed. The name was changed because Facebook worries that apps beginning with fb might be mistaken as belonging to Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to your Facebook events page: https://www.facebook.com/events/
2. In the "You can add your events to Microsoft Outlook, Google Calendar..." box, RIGHT mouse click on the "Upcoming Events" link
3. Select "Copy link address" from the menu
4. Go your Google Calendar page, click on the gear/settings icon and select "Settings," click on "Add calendar" in the left nav menu and select "From URL" to end up here: https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/settings/addbyurl
5. Paste the URL of your Facebook events saved in your clipboard into the "URL of calendar" input
6. Click on "ADD CALENDAR" link

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, if you use Chrome, you can register Google Calendar to open webcal: links automatically.  Go to https://calendar.google.com, click on the two-diamonds icon next to the bookmark, choose to allow it to open webcal links, and this will open the Windows settings panel to confirm.  Then you can click on the `webcal://www.facebook.com/ical/u.php?uid=...` link from your events page as above and it will automatically import into Google Calendar.